# Show sibling element on mouseover using angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have many repeated content elements in a single view. Within each content element, there's an anchor. When a user mouses over this anchor, I want to toggle a class on a sibling element within that particular content element.

Here's a simple example of what I want to do:

```
<div class="content-element">
  <div ng-class="visibleClass">
    I should have class 'visible' when the user mouses over the link within content-element div.
  </div>
  <a ng-mouseover="" ng-mouseleave="" href="#">Mouseover</a>
</div>
```

I initially wrote a controller to handle this, but the controller's $scope is tied to the entire view, not a single content-element, so this turned out to not be a graceful solution.

There are many 'content-elements' that are not generated with angular, but are just repeated in the template.

I'm fairly new to angular and trying to wrap my head around this new way of thinking. I can definitely solve this problem easy writing some javascript (capture the event, get the target, get the sibling, etc.) but this doesn't seem like the proper way to do it with angular.

So... what's the appropriate angular way to do this? Should I be writing a custom directive?

Comment: This should be done in a directive. Please provide a plunkr or jsfiddle so we can help you do that

Comment: Here's a plunkr with the basic setup: http://plnkr.co/edit/nlmOHtoZLug3mJ59mRFu?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a directive with a new scope and have something like this in the HTML:

```
<div class="content-item">
  <div class="" ng-class="{someClass:hovered}">My transparency should change.</div>
  <a ng-mouseover="hovered = true">Mouseover me.</a>
</div>
```

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/RaUVbnPSuwGEU4dkMQ31?p=preview)

Note that if you use `ngRepeat`, it creates isolate scopes automatically and you don't need the directive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thanks for the additional info regarding isolate scope. Very helpful! I've successfully got this working with a really simple directive (per your PLUNKER example).

Answer (score 1):

Directive which founds siblings of the element on mouseover event. You can do what you want with the siblings then:

```
app.directive('mousiee',function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
      var siblings;
      elem.on('mouseover',function(){
        siblings = $(elem.parent()).siblings();
        console.log(siblings);
      });
    }
  };

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/gWkNpiHMUEUBwuug9C3q?p=preview

(Note that I've added jQuery to your index.html)